Is there a way to create a column with interval type in QuestDB?
I'm trying to create a table with the following schema in QuestDB:
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  id LONG,
  task_interval INTERVAL,
  ts TIMESTAMP
) TIMESTAMP(ts) PARTITION BY DAY;

I can see INTERVAL type in the documentation, but the database returns me an "non-persisted type: interval" error. Is it possible to create an INTERVAL column in QuestDB?

You're getting this error because in QuestDB INTERVAL type is only used for inputs and return values of SQL functions, e.g.
SELECT *
FROM tasks
WHERE ts in today();

Here, today() SQL function returns an INTERVAL value.
Since an INTERVAL is a tuple holding two TIMESTAMP values, you can create two TIMESTAMP columns to fix your DDL statement:
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  id LONG,
  task_start TIMESTAMP,
  task_end TIMESTAMP,
  ts TIMESTAMP
) TIMESTAMP(ts) PARTITION BY DAY;

And if you need an INTERVAL value in your SQL, you can convert two TIMESTAMPs to an INTERVAL with the interval() function:
SELECT interval(task_start, task_end)
FROM tasks;

